# How do I reduce the amount of queries of my Django app?

Tags: python, django

My app is currently making over 1000 SQL queries and taking around 20s to load the page. I can't seem to find a way to come up with a solution to get the same data displayed on a table in my template faster. I wan't to display 100 results so that's way my pagination is set to 100.

These are the methods in my my **models.py** used to get the count and sum of the orders, these two are in my Company model and the get_order_count is also in my Contact model

```
def get_order_count(self):
    orders = 0
    for order in self.orders.all():
        orders += 1
    return orders

def get_order_sum(self):
    total_sum = 0
    for contact in self.contacts.all():
        for order in contact.orders.all():
            total_sum += order.total
    return total_sum
```

## views.py

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = "mailer/index.html"
    model = Company
    paginate_by = 100
```

## template

```
{% for company in company_list %}
    <tr id="company-row">
        <th id="company-name" scope="row">{{ company.name }}</th>
        <td>{{ company.get_order_count }}</td>
        <td id="order-sum">{{ company.get_order_sum|floatformat:2 }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
           <input type="checkbox" name="select{{company.pk}}" id="">
       </td>
    </tr>
    {% for contact in company.contacts.all %}
        <tr id="contact-row">
            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
            <td>{{ contact.first_name }} {{ contact.last_name }}</td>
            <td id="contact-orders">
                Orders: {{ contact.get_order_count }} 
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your two methods are very inefficient. You can replace them with annotations which calculate everything in one query in the database. You haven't shown your models, but it would be something like:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = "mailer/index.html"
    model = Company.objects.annotate(order_count=Count('orders')).annotate(order_sum=Sum('contacts__orders__total'))
    paginate_by = 100
```

Now you can access `{{ company.order_count }}` and `{{ company.order_sum }}`.